# Can contents of a script or image tag be read after it is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, security

Let's say I have a `<script>` tag in my html and it loads some script from it's source. Is it possible to read this source as a string somehow (without executing the same request to src directly)? The point is to figure out if there is some vulnerability that needs to be addressed, since e.g. script source can be a 3d party API and browser is happy to send the authentication cookies.

I assume it is not possible and has to be strictly forbidden since otherwise it can be used in a CSRF attack easily to steal sensitive data, but just want to be sure.

P.S. The same goes for e.g. `<img>` tag, etc.

Comment: If it's a `<script>code</script>` tag you can use `.textContent`, but I don't think there's a way to access the contents of an external JS file.

Comment: If your motivation is to make sure that the script has not been modified, then subresource integrity might be an option to dealing with the problem more directly: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can't do this from the browser. The same-origin policy prevents the browser from reading the contents of contents (script or img) from a different origin (domain).

And even in the cases when you can read the source (using CORS), there is no way to do this until after the browser has already parsed and executed the script. If that's what you are after, then you would use subresource integrity to whitelist allowed scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no I don't need to execute the script, but tried to figure out if an attack possible if you try to execute a 3d party api that e.g. returns json instead of real script and then read it. I though that SOP would prevent it and it seems it does as you say

Comment: You're welcome. One idea could be to send the URL of the 3rd party script to an external service which can do the analysis and return the response (with CORS so you can read it). I don't know if that's relevant to your use case but maybe worth investigating.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://localhost:8081/myscript.js';

    xhr.open('GET', url);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(response) {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(response.currentTarget.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Well, that would work, but my point was to load data (or figure out if it's a vulnerability) from another server, so that your solution would be prevented by CORS, I will edit my answer a bit, it was not clear enough.